# Can a Wordpress Plugin be Converted For Use On Non WP Website?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I want to be able to validate SEO rules on a html form. E.g. Check keyword is in title, images have alt tags etc. Wordpress has a brilliant tool for this(Yoast SEO for Wordpress), but i checked the website and they dont have a standalone download. I also cant find any tool to do this elsewhere so before i write it myself i want to see if i can pull it from this plugin.

All i need is the jquery side of this tool (I just want it as a guideline not as a requirement).

I have been able to get all of the Javascript and css files by looking at the page source from a Wordpress site, but there is a lot of other stuff within the page including 126 refrences to "seo" so its going to be a big job to extract all of the information that i need.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is? If the jquery isn't using WP specific functions / variables, then yes, you should be able to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes it can be converted to be used on any php website, but you need to change things in that plugin according to the Non WP sites so that it can be used on Non WP sites. You also need to find substitute functions for that plugin for the functions that are wordpress specific.